# Is it possible to avoid updating drupal core with composer update?

Tags: docker, drupal, composer-php

I'm trying to build a docker container where the dockerfile installs a specific version of drupal, I copy over custom copies of composer.json/composer.lock and then do a composer update to download the contributed modules specified in these composer files. I know that ideally composer would also control core, but for this project, I'm trying to avoid that.

The problem I'm having is that composer update seems to also reinstall drupal, where I want the dockerfile to be in control of this and I'd like composer to just manage the modules.

Is this something I could do by modifying the composer files (so far tests have not worked)? It seems you can't specify a package for composer to ignore and where I see you can specify specific packages to update, that's not really a viable solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's looking like the issue was the composer.lock/json files I was adding to run composer update were initially created by using composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project, which installed core and thus added it to the composer.lock/json files.

It seems that by just reinstalling the contributed modules with composer in a fresh drupal site (so simplified composer files) might be the answer.